# Click EventHandler not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

My newly created button in my gridviewrow is not firing its EventHandler or the RowCmmand Event and then when the page Reload after pressing the Button newly added row is missing probably because I can't call my BindData method. I have removed the Click eventHandler from the Button and just used the OnRowCommand Event and I still am getting nothing

```
protected void CustomGridView_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = ((GridView)sender).Rows.Count;
    GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(-1, -1, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Insert);

    TableCell cell = new TableCell();
    Button button = new Button();
    button.Text = "Insert";
    button.ID = "Insert";
    button.CommandName = "Insert";
    button.Click += new EventHandler(insertButton_Click);

    cell.Controls.Add(button);
    row.Cells.Add(cell);

    for (int i = 0; i < ((GridView)sender).Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        cell = new TableCell();
        cell.Controls.Add(new TextBox { ID = "Text" + i });
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
    }

    Table table = ((GridView)sender).Rows[0].Parent as Table;
    table.Rows.AddAt(count + 1, row);
}

protected void insertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblInsert.Text = "Hello World";
}

protected void CustomGridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Insert")
    {
        lblInsert.Text = "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Comment: There must be always a solid reason  - why code is not running as expected. Please be specific and rephrase your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `button.Click += new EventHandler(insertButton_Click);` statement from your code. The `RowCommand` event of GridView controll will be fired when button is pressed. For more info - [How to: Respond to Button Events in a GridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907626.aspx).

Comment: @KDM - In code snippet, you are adding row at Rows[0]. What is reason to add a TableRow at Rows[0]?

Comment: No im adding a row to the end of the gridview. Rows[0].Parent gets me the table of the gridview correct me if im wrong so I can make changes

Comment: I got it to work it registered finally. for some reason it just wasn't working i did what you said and it worked

Comment: @KDM - Thanks! May be you might forgot to bind GridView on each postback. (Dynamically added controls must be created, registered their events on each postback).

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach to the grid's RowCommand event before the databound. Do it on the constructor or Init event of the page or usercontrol, not in the databound. In the databound you will set the CommandName and CommandArgument properties.

Hope it helps.